# Is there a general rule of thumb for when to use modal segues and when to use push segues in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios5

Is there a general rule of thumb for when to use modal segues and when to use push segues in iOS?

that is, when creating a new screen that segues from an exiting screen, what questions should I ask myself before deciding on the correct segue? Any advice, background info etc. would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/TechnologyUsage/TechnologyUsage.html) (HIG) says:

> it’s a good idea to use the modal presentation style when users are
>   expecting a change in experience, such as after they complete a task

A push segue should be used for navigation within the app (such as in a navigation view controller)

Additionaly, the [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW24) says:

> Modality is most appropriate when:
>
> It’s critical to get the user’s attention. A task must be completed
>   (or explicitly abandoned) to avoid leaving the user’s data in an
>   ambiguous state.